# Is it necessary to add install referer decryption key in facebook client app registering?

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, oauth, facebook-oauth

[image]

Hey I want to create facebook client app in facebook developer portal. I'm going to use this for facebook sigin(oauth) in my react-native app. Do I have to input 'install referer decryption key' and 'class name'? I'm still in development.

And do I have to change them when I release the app to playstore?